# Is it possible to see "text" version of NpgSqlCommand before execution?

Tags: c#, npgsql

I want to see a text version of the command I am about to execute that was created using parameters.add - is there a way to do this? (See commented out line below.)

```
   NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
    conn.Open();
    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into \"Min_Bar_Price_Data\" values(:SEC_ID, :PX_OPEN, :PX_HIGH, :PX_LOW, :PX_LAST, :PX_VOLUME, :Date)", conn);


cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("SEC_ID", DbType.Int32));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("PX_OPEN", DbType.Double));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("PX_HIGH", DbType.Double));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("PX_LOW", DbType.Double));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("PX_LAST", DbType.Double));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("PX_VOLUME", DbType.Double));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("Date", DbType.DateTime));


    cmd.Parameters["SEC_ID"].Value = sec_ID;
    cmd.Parameters["PX_OPEN"].Value = 0.0;
    cmd.Parameters["PX_HIGH"].Value = 0.0;
    cmd.Parameters["PX_LOW"].Value = 0.0;
    cmd.Parameters["PX_LAST"].Value = d.Close;
    cmd.Parameters["PX_VOLUME"].Value = 1.0;
    cmd.Parameters["Date"].Value = d.DT;
```

> //Console.WriteLine("Created command: " + cmd.????);

```
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire idea of [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) is that parameters are transmitted [out-of-band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_data), as opposed to being "substituted" into the SQL statement. This is done to prevent SQL injection attacks and for optimization purposes.

If only for debugging purposes, you can replace parameter names with appropriate values manually, with a simple regex.

Comment: I understand that. The reason I ask is that I want to prepare a single insert statement with multiple values. BUT I would like to use "parameters" to ensure I send correct values.

Comment: As @anton-gogolev says, parameters aren't substituted into your query - at no point is there a string with all your parameters. Npgsql 3.0.4 (not yet released) will provide an SQL logging feature - including parameters - which may help you out (see https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/839). However, it will log for all statements, not just the ones you want.